# How to get the PK of a new item created in the database to use right away and update it's settings

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC, entityframework and angular as the front-end.

In my angular application I have Stepper component https://material.angular.io/components/stepper

In the first step I want to fill out my form and as soon as I click next I want to create the task and on the second form I want to update the settings for that newly created task. However, I need to get the PK of the newly created task to update the settings on my second form.

There is an api call to create a new task in the tTask table in sqlserver.

This is my API Post Method.

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(CreatingTaskModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult PosttTask(CreatingTaskModel CreatingTaskModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var newtTask= new tTask
        {
            TaskName = CreatingTaskModel.TaskName,
            TaskDescription = CreatingTaskModel.TaskDescription,
            EmailSubject = CreatingTaskModel.EmailSubject,
            EmailBody = CreatingTaskModel.EmailBody,
            FK_TaskTeam = CreatingTaskModel.tTaskTeam.pk_TaskTeam,
            Enabled = CreatingTaskModel.Enabled ? 1:0,

        };
        db.tTasks.Add(newtTask);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var pk = new {id = CreatingTaskModel.PK_Task};

        return Ok("Success");
    }
```

This is the submit code in angular :

```
onSubmit()
{
    if(this.taskForm.valid) 
    {
        this.service.createTask(this.taskForm.value).subscribe((data) => {
        debugger;
        console.log(data)
        }) 
    }

}
```

I saw that return Ok() in my webapi returns a message and I was thinking of sorting the tTask table by decending order of after the             db.SaveChanges();
and returning the last item that it find and sending it back in the Ok(pk) and then casting that into an integer on my client-side and using that to get the data to update it.

What is the correct way to do this? Should it be done in sql or on the webapi?

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    var newObject = new
    {
        id = newtTask.PK_Task,
        message = "Success"

    };
    return Ok(newObject);
```

and on angular I have this:

```
 onSubmit(){
    if(this.taskForm.valid) {
      this.service.createTask(this.taskForm.value).subscribe((data) => {
        if(data.message){ 
          if(data.message == "Success"){
            this.getRecipentData(data.id);


this.AdditionalRecipientForm.controls['FK_Task'].setValue(data.id);
            this.pk_Task =  data.id;

          }
        }
        debugger;
        console.log(data)
      }) 
    }
```

It just doesn't seem practical to do this, but it does the job. What do you guys think? Should I maybe instead of going to the serve twice maybe after it goes to the done filling out both forms submit them both? Like call create method in my API and then call my second API to update the data the was submitted in the second form. I am just looking for ideas or most common practice for these types of situations.

Answer (score 1):

After you've added it to the database and called `db.SaveChanges`, the key will be assigned to the object.  So, after `db.SaveChanges`, you should just be able to simply reference `newtTask.Id`.

Comment: Yea, that works, but is there another way to do this? Should I create a seprate controller to handle this part or leave in the create put method of my API?

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you manually assign the id of the new task via `PK_Task = CreatingTaskModel.PK_Task,` and that it's indeed this id that gets saved to the Db. Therefore the id column should not be autoincrementing.

If that's true you can, as Louis said before, simply return your object or only the id if you're concerned about bandwidth.

You can do `return new OkObjectResult(pk);` or just use the shorthand: `return Ok(pk);`, which will also return an OkObjectResult with the pk object as payload.

Comment: Okay, the idColumn is autoincrementing, sorry about the confusion. I think that is bad practice of me to leave the PK in there when I wasn't sending a PK and it was getting assigned 0 and it would still autoincrement in the database. Anyways, Louis does work and I get the PK of the newly created PK. Does this seem right? OR should I just create another controller to get the PK?

Comment: Directly returning it is fine and actually what I do in my projects. An extra controller is to much overhead just for this in my opinion.

Comment: One more question, can you look at my question where it shows the client-side code. Am I recieving the PK correctly? I am sending an object and in the subcribe((data) => {data}) 
data has the PK value or is there another way I should be receiving the value?